# Pointer manipulation

Tags: c, pointers

```
char statement[1052]="test", *a=inet_ntoa(iphdr->ip_src);
char c[20]="1";
strcpy(c,a);
char *b=inet_ntoa(iphdr->ip_dst);
snprintf(statement, 1052, "INSERT INTO tblname(ip1,ip2) VALUES ('%s','%s')",c,b);
printf("%s\n,statement);
```

This works correctly , but when I try to remove the second and third line, the value of b gets printed in a.

Comment: This seems to be expected, as the second and third line change the contents of `a`. What exactly is the question?

Comment: the documentation is pretty clear on that `The string is returned in a statically allocated buffer, which subsequent calls will overwrite` [see here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_ntoa)

Comment: `inet_ntoa()` returns a pointer to static buffer within the library, which is reused on every call. You can verify this by `fprintf(stderr, %p %p\n, (void*)a, (void*)b);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_ntoa

> The inet_ntoa() function converts the Internet host address in, given
>   in network byte order, to a string in IPv4 dotted-decimal notation.
>   The string is returned in a **statically allocated buffer, which
>   subsequent calls will overwrite**.

The second call to `inet_ntoa` is overwriting the result of the first one. You need to copy the value out to your own storage each time.

Specifically, in your example, both `a` and `b` will end up pointing to the same address, in memory which is owned by the `inet_ntoa` implementation.